# Can I refresh an XML comment in Visual Studio to reflect parameters that have changed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments

If I write the function:

```
    public static uint FindAUint(double firstParam)
    {

    }
```

I can generate the xml comments by typing '///', it gives :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// *Here I type the summary of the method*
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstParam">*Summary of param*</param>
    /// <returns>*Summary of return*</returns>
    public static uint FindAUint(double firstParam)
    {

    }
```

If I then decide I need to update my method to be:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// *Here I type the summary of the method*
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstParam">*Summary of param*</param>
    /// <returns>*Summary of return*</returns>
    public static uint FindAUint(double firstParam,double newParam, double newParam2)
    {

    }
```

Is there a way to get visual studio to add the new params into the xml without losing the descriptions of the previous ones?

(I should mention I am using Visual Studio Express; I wouldn't put it past Microsoft to disallow the feature in the Express version though)

Comment: AFAIK, is you're just using VS, you gotta enter 'em manually

Comment: If you type `<param name="` it will only populate the IntelliSense window with a list of parameters that you don't currently have documented. Not a solution, just a handy tip that might help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).  It is a Visual Studio extension that will generate your XML comments for you.

Comment: Will that preserve the existing comments, and only add XML for the new parameters?

Comment: It will remove the comments for parameter that no longer exist and add any that are missing.  It does not overwrite anything.  It will also generate default descriptions for methods, properties, parameters, etc.

Comment: I can't work in Visual Studio without GhostDoc and Resharper.

Comment: Thanks @cadrell0, I only am using Express, so don't have this option, but it definitely answers the question. Maybe I should have a conversation with my boss about getting some licenses, though I am not sure he cares about the ease of commenting on my code.

Comment: @NominSim If you are writing code professionally, you should really have the full version.  I believe Express is meant for students and non-commercial use.

Comment: @cadrell0 There are no licensing restrictions on Express, haven't seen a real need to get the full version yet, as (albeit with some hoop-jumping) all I need to do with it can be accomplished with Express.

Answer (score 6):

[ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) works very nice for me; it warns whenever the XML comment does not match a method's signature.

Also, using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keyboard shortcut, ReSharper can fix these mismatches by adding/removing the necessary XML comments.

Comment: I just see one drawback with this method; if the method doesn't have any <param> section in the xml comments, even if there are parameters in the method, Resharper will not suggest to add the missing parameters. But in anyways, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to select the current block of XML Documentation and to comment it out. Then create a new line under the commented out code. A new XML Documentation block will be created with all the new values and you can copy paste your old values.

Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bar">True if not false</param>
/// <returns>Some really important value</returns>
public bool Foo(bool bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

Changes to method

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bar">True if not false</param>
/// <returns>Some really important name</returns>
public string Foo(bool bar, string bar2, int bar3) {
    if (bar) {
        return bar2 + bar3.ToString();
    } else {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

Comment out the documentation

```
///// <summary>
///// Does something
///// </summary>
///// <param name="bar">True if not false</param>
///// <returns>Some really important name</returns>
public string Foo(bool bar, string bar2, int bar3) {
    if (bar) {
        return bar2 + bar3.ToString();
    } else {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

In a new line under the commented out code enter `///` to get the generated XML Documentation.

```
///// <summary>
///// Does something
///// </summary>
///// <param name="bar">True if not false</param>
///// <returns>Some really important value</returns>
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bar"></param>
/// <param name="bar2"></param>
/// <param name="bar3"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string Foo(bool bar, string bar2, int bar3) {
    if (bar) {
        return bar2 + bar3.ToString();
    } else {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```