# XML Documentation Comments Actualization in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Is there possibility in Visual Studio 2010 to actualize an XML documentation comment autmatically after adding or removing a parameter in a method?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451482/can-i-refresh-an-xml-comment-in-visual-studio-to-reflect-parameters-that-have-ch

There you find some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). This tool has a lot of features for fixing and automating code documentation within Visual Studio.